# DiagrammeR: How could I use a different color for some nodes of a flowchart?

Tags: r, graph, colors, flowchart, diagrammer

I want to create a flowchart with the `DiagrammeR` package in R. The color of the flowchart should be set according to an identifier at the beginning of each variable name.

Consier the following reproducible example:

```
library("DiagrammeR")

# Create a node data frame (ndf)
ndf <- create_node_df(n = 4,
                      label = c("^color", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"))

# Create an edge data frame (edf)
edf <- create_edge_df(from = c(1, 2, 3, 3),
                      to = c(4, 3, 1, 4))

# Create a graph with the ndf and edf
graph <- create_graph(nodes_df = ndf,
                      edges_df = edf) %>%
  set_global_graph_attrs(
    attr = c("style", "fillcolor"),
    value = c("filled", "darkolivegreen3"),
    attr_type = c("node", "node"))

# Create a PDF file for the graph (`graph.pdf`)
graph %>%
  render_graph()
```

[image]

With the `set_global_graph_attrs` function, I am able to set the global colors. I would like to color every variable with ^ in the beginning in red. In the example, the variable ^color should be colored red. The rest of the flowchart should be kept green. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a solution for this problem.

**Question: How could I use a different color for some nodes of my flowchart?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the node attributes individually like this.

```
ndf$fillcolor = as.character(NA)
ndf$fillcolor[grep('\\^', ndf$label)] = 'red'
```

[image]